# Apache Beam apply centralized configuration using Spring Cloud Config

Tags: apache-beam

We have a requirement to move configuration properties to a centralized Spring Cloud Config Server. For example the path of the Input files and the path to write output files. Could you please tell if Spring Cloud Config Client can be integrated in Apache Beam framework and Beam programs can read configuration properties from Spring Config Server. We are using Spark runner to run Beam programs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I created a spring-boot app running inside of Flink and the trick is to set the following property in the bootstrap.yml

spring:
  main:
    web-environment: false

It works.